# How to HTML tags to bootstrap tool-tip title?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am trying to add HTML tags to bootstrap tool-tip. I tried many ways but nothing worked for me. My current code is:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<p> My Code </p>" data-placement="bottom"></a>
```

And jQuery Code:

```
 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({html:true});
```

Comment: You also don't have any text in the anchor tag itself so there's no link text to hover on.

Comment: By reading your question, I am not clear about what behaviour you are expecting. You want to add HTML tags, so the tags are displayed into the tooltip? (by moving the mouse, you see `<h3>My Code</h3>` inside the tooltip), or your want to add HTML tags, so the tags are not visible, but rather than that, you see the effect of adding the tags to the code? (by moving the mouse, you see just `My Code` in a `<h3>` title)

Comment: Just for clarify the above comment: I am using as an example `<h3>My Code</h3>` instead of `<p>My Code</p>` (as the question is), just because a title element is more bigger and notorious than a paragraph element, when using both inside a tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the HTML character codes. So

```
<p> My Code </p>
```

becomes

```
&lt;p&gt; My Code &lt;/p&gt;
```

Comment: Not Working. I am getting `<p> My Code  </p>` in tool tip.

Comment: Actually in tooltips you can simply use the HTML tags. Popovers are the ones that are more complex. Just to be sure... you are wrapping the initializer in document.ready, right? I tested initializing before and it didn't work.